# Error 1004 - Vlookup in vba - Unable to get the Vlookup property of the WorksheetFunction class

Tags: forms, vba, excel, vlookup

I've browsed the various questions already asked with this issue other users have faced and none of the solutions seem to fix the error code coming up.

I have a form which prompts the user for a reference number - they input this into the text field and then press OK

```
'OK button from form1
    Public Sub CommandButton1_Click()
    refInput = refTextBox.Value
    InputRef.Hide
    ExportShipForm.Show
    End Sub
```

Once this has been pressed, the next form appears which I would like to be populated with data based on the reference number input on the first form. I have an update button which will update the "labels" on the form to show the data - this is where I am getting an error.
The first label to update is through a Vlookup:

Below the users clicks the update button the 2nd form:

```
Public Sub btnUpdate_Click()
Call ICS_Caption

lbl_ICS.Caption = Label_ICS
End Sub
```

This calls a function below:

```
Public Sub ICS_Caption()
Dim ws1 As Worksheet

refInput = InputRef.refTextBox.Value
Set ws1 = Worksheets("MACRO")

dataRef = Worksheets("Shipping Data").Range("A:K")
Label_ICS = WorksheetFunction.VLookup(refInput, dataRef, 7, False)
End Sub
```

The error continues to come up each time - I have ran the vlookup manually in a cell outside of VBA and it works fine.
I have typed the range in the Vlookup whilst also using named ranges but each variation shows the same error.

Eventually, I would want the label on form 2 to update with the result of the Vlookup.

Any ideas?

Comment: Could you update your question with what error you are getting?

Comment: Hi DragonSamu, have updated the title with the error

Comment: Can you check the type of `refInput` before line `Label_ICS = WorksheetFunction.VLookup(refInput, dataRef, 7, False)`.

Comment: In general I recommend you go back and Dim each variable as its specifc type; VBA allows you to use variables without doing this, but often causes pain when you don't realize that Excel has assumed the variable is type A, but you are trying to use it like type B (ie: string vs integer etc)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to `Dim dataRef as Range` and then `Set` it.

See code Below:

```
Dim DataRef as Range
Set dataRef = Worksheets("Shipping Data").Range("A:K")
```

Just like a `Workbook` or `Worksheet` you need to `Set` the `Range`

Just as Grade 'Eh' Bacon suggest in comments its always best to `Dim` every reference.
The best way to do so is to put `Option Explicit` all the way at the top of your code. This forces you to define everything which helps it preventing mistakes/typo's etc.

**Update edit:**

The problem was you are looking for a Reference number in your `Sheet` (thus an `Integer`) but `refInput` is set as a `String` this conflicts and `.VLookup` throws an error because it can't find a match.

I have reworked your code:

Your sub is now a function which returns the `.Caption String`

```
Function ICS_Caption(refInput As Integer)
    Dim dataRef As Range
    Set dataRef = Worksheets("Shipping Data").Range("A:K")
    ICS_Caption = WorksheetFunction.VLookup(refInput, dataRef, 7, False)
End Function
```

The update Button calls your `Function` and provides the data:

```
Public Sub btnUpdate_Click()
    lbl_ICS.Caption = ICS_Caption(InputRef.refTextBox.Value)
End Sub
```

By using a `Function` you can provide the `Integer` value and get a return value back without the need of having `Global` Strings or Integers.

Which would have been your next obstacle as you can only transfer `Variables` between `Modules/Userforms`  by using a `Global` `Variable`.

I would even advice to directly use the function in the `Initialize Event` of your 2nd `Userform` to load the data before the `Userform` shows this is more user friendly then needing to provide data and then still needing to push an update button.

Comment: Hi DragonSamu, I have added on Option Explicit to all modules and forms and have also applied dim to every reference. However, the error is still appearing. Both DataRef and inputRef have been assigned a dim (range and integer respectively) but no joy. Ben has suggested below having the correct libraries - I have Visual basic for applications/MS Excel 15.0 Obj library/OLE Automation/MS Office 15.0 obj library/MS Forms 2.0 obj library.

Comment: @jamesc100 I have looked into how `.VLookup` works and the data you are searching for has to be present (if you use `.VLookup`) in the first `Column` if not present there it will throw the error. Is the data you search for present in the first `Column`? I have tested your code and it works perfect IF your search data is present in the first `Column`

Comment: The data is present in the first column yes. The vLookup is trying to find refInput which is in the first column in the range "DataRef".

Comment: @jamesc100 If you can please upload your file and post the link so I can take a look, as i stated I tested your code with a Userform but got no errors.

Comment: https://www.dropbox.com/s/r0612gxusvz4rks/export%20shipping%202015%20v2.xlsm?dl=0  - @DragonSamu - Here is the link to the file

Comment: It works! Your help is very much appreciated, thank you!

Answer (score 0):

1. Verify that you have no missing libraries in VBA IDE > Tools > References
2. Try using a worksheet cell as the place to store and retrieve refTextBox.Value, rather than refInput (which I assume is a global variable):

   ```
   Public Sub CommandButton1_Click()
   ...
   Worksheets("Shipping Data").Range($M$1).Value=refTextBox.Value  
   End Sub

   Public Sub ICS_Caption()
   Dim refInput as Long'My assumption
   ...
   refInput=Worksheets("Shipping Data").Range($M$1).Value
   ...
   End Sub
   ```
3. Make sure you have `Option Explicit` at the top of all of your code windows.

Comment: Can you explain the logic of storing your data into the `Workbook` instead of a `Variable`? I really don't see the logic in that.

Comment: It would rule out errors with Form 2 attempting to access an object on Form 1 that was no longer available - it would have been a possibility before the clarification to the full error message was posted. I don't think it's relevant now.